# Next.js routing works forward but has problem backward

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router, next-router

I have difficulties to understand how the next.js routing works and I think I'm using it wrong.
When I navigate forward through the pages with Link, I have no problem, but when I use the browser back button it sometimes reload the previous page and sometimes stays on the same page whereas the url changed. Then I need to refresh the page manually

I guess this is something I do wrong, but can't figure out what

index.js :

```
import Head from "next/head";
import NewBooks from "../components/Homepage";
import { getProducts } from "../utils/api";

const HomePage = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Classe moyenne éditions</title>
      </Head>
      <NewBooks products={products} />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const products = await getProducts();
  return { props: { products } };
}

export default HomePage;
```

books/index.js :

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Catalogue from "../../components/Catalogue";
import { getProducts } from "../../utils/api";

const CataloguePage = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Catalogue</title>
      </Head>
      <Catalogue products={products} />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const products = await getProducts();
  return { props: { products } };
}

export default CataloguePage;
```

- component/Catalogue.js :

  import Link from "next/link";
  import { getStrapiMedia } from "../utils/medias";
  import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

  const Catalogue = ({ products }) => {

  ```
  return (

    <div className="container-cat">
        {products.map((_product) => (
          <Card id="lien" key={_product.id} alt="book" className="items">
            <Link href='/books/[name]' as={`/books/${encodeURIComponent(_product.name)}`}>
              <a>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={getStrapiMedia(_product.grid_pic.url)} width="200px" />
                  <Card.Title>{_product.name}<br />{_product.author}<br />{_product.price} €</Card.Title>
                </Card.Body>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </Card>

        ))
        }
    </div>

  );
  ```

  };

  export default Catalogue;

Comment: Please provide a basic reproducible example

Comment: For exemple : I'm on the homepage ('/'), click on shop button, landing on the shop page ('/books'). If I click on the browser back button the url goes back to ('/), but the screen still rends the shop component. I don't know what part of code I can provide

Comment: For that exemple, on the file tree, the home page is /inder.js and the shop page is /books/index.js

Comment: Providing your `/index.js` and `/books/index.js` would be helpful.

Comment: have you figures this out @Rom-888? I am having the same problem

Comment: No! I put this on hold for a while, but still not solved. Sorry

Comment: Hi everyone! I've been faced with a similar issue that I describe here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69122288/next-js-router-doesnt-react-on-browsers-backward-button-on-some-pages

There is a clickable example (production url) and some attempts to debug that failed.

If anyone has an idea of what to check, how to debug, I would be grateful!