# Next.js router doesn't react on browser's backward button on some pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've faced with hard to investigate bug with the browser's backward button on `https://gart.gallery`.

If you go to `https://gart.gallery/artworks/`
then to any artwork, for example, `https://gart.gallery/artworks/my-place/` then click browser's backward –– the URL will be replaced by `/artworks` but the new page wouldn't be rendered.

My attempts to debug:

1. it doesn't relate to page content – if the page is `const Artwork = () => <p>Artwork page</p>` the behavior stays the same
2. it doesn't relate to pages files structure

```
   pages/arworks/index.tsx
   pages/arworks/[slug]/index.tsx
   // everything is usual
```

3. next.js is able to work proper because `/events/art-dubai/` and `/events` navigate through the browser back/forward correctly
4. I tried but in vain to find the difference between `/events/[slug]` which works correctly and `/arworks/[slug]`, `/artworks` pages. Moreover, I tried to replace them with the simplest possible component with just a `<p>` or `Link` – behavior stays the same.
5. This bug actual only for `arworks/[slug] => artworks`, `galleries/[slug] => galleries` and `artists/[slug] => artists` but not for `/events/[slug] => /events`. Weird, I don't see what is in common or what is the difference
6. I've noticed that next.js router doesn't fire the event when I click backward on problemed pages and does on navigating every other page. I have a subscription in the `_app.tsx` on the events like:

```
   function handleStart(...props) {
     console.log('start ', JSON.stringify(props));
     start('ROUTER', 0);
   }
   function handleStop(...props) {
     console.log('complete ', JSON.stringify(props));
     finish('ROUTER', 500);
   }
   router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleStart);
   router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleStop);
```

I can provide any needed configs or files if it helps.

I do not hope to get a final solution, but I would be very grateful if someone could direct me on the way how to think/debug this.

UPDATE:

If i change NextLink on simple  ...  – it navigates to the artwork and than browsers backward works properly! So the issue has been localized: it is a problem with using NextLink. But still not clear why pages navigated through NextLink don't trigger the router to re-render component due to URL has been changed. I use Next link due to the doc:

```
<NextLink
  passHref
  href="/artworks/[slug]"
  as={`/artworks/${product.slug}`}
/>
  <a>...</a>
</NextLink>
```

Removing `passHref` or using just a `href` property – does no impact on bug.

Comment: I see some errors on [slug] page, like `Error: <path> attribute d`, `Portal render failed` and so on. Maybe it is somehow related to the bug? Otherwise, I don't think it is possible to deduct what is going on without reproduction on https://codesandbox.io/ or something

Comment: Can you share the code of the component that you are rendering on route **/artworks/**?

Comment: No, errors in the console don't relate to the bug – there are SVG issues, 3rd party ui components errors, etc.

Yes, but the whole component has no impact on the issue due to the fact that I simplified it to

```
artworks.map(aw => (
<p>
<NextLink passHref href="/artworks/[slug]" as={`/artworks/${product.slug}`}>
  <a>{product.slug}</a>
</NextLink>
</p>
));
```
And the wrong behaviout remains

Comment: But I have found what does impact! If i change NextLink on simple  <a href={`/artworks/${product.slug}`}> ... </a> – it navigates to the artwork and than browsers backward works properly!

So the issue has been localized: it is a problem with using NextLink. But still not clear why pages navigated through NextLink don't trigger the router to re-render component due to URL has been changed.

Comment: If you change it to regular `a` anchor then there will be full page reload. How are you using Next Link, could you post that part (just update the question)?

Comment: Changing `nextLink` on `a` is a temporary-hot-fix, but I still can't figure out why `nextLink` navigation causes the bug behavior.